# Does the center of the Milky Way galaxy taste of raspberries?

Tags: astronomy, taste

An [article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2009/apr/21/space-raspberries-amino-acids-astrobiology) (2009) from *The Guardian* claims that the center of the Milky Way tastes of raspberries:

> Astronomers searching for the [building blocks of life](https://www.theguardian.com/science/biochemistrymolecularbiology) in a giant dust cloud at the heart of the Milky Way have concluded that it would taste vaguely of raspberries.
>
> The unanticipated discovery follows years of work by astronomers who trained their 30m radio telescope on the enormous ball of dust and gas in the hope of spotting complex molecules that are vital for life.
>
> Finding amino acids in interstellar space is a Holy Grail for astrobiologists, as this would raise the possibility of life emerging on other planets after being seeded with the molecules.
>
> In the latest survey, astronomers sifted through thousands of signals from Sagittarius B2, a vast dust cloud at the centre of our galaxy. While they failed to find evidence for amino acids, they did find a substance called ethyl formate, the chemical responsible for the flavour of raspberries.
>
> "It does happen to give raspberries their flavour, but there are many other molecules that are needed to make space raspberries," Arnaud Belloche, an astronomer at the [Max Planck Institute for Radio Astronomy](http://www.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/english/) in Bonn, told the Guardian.
>
> -["Galaxy's centre tastes of raspberries and smells of rum, say astronomers"](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2009/apr/21/space-raspberries-amino-acids-astrobiology), The Guardian (2009-04-20)

Has this been confirmed by other sources?

Comment: I guess that this would be a two-part question: **(1)** Have other sources supported the finding of these chemicals in the center of the Milky Way? **(2)** Do these chemicals taste like raspberries?

Comment: @Nat: Right, except the second claim is just whimsy as the last two paragraphs explain. There is no claim to debunk there. The only claim is "Does the Sagittarius B2 dust cloud contain ethyl formate?"

Comment: One thing t know about astronomy is that the universe is 3 dimensional and vast but our view of it is 2 dimensional.  Thus things are often said to be "in" or "at" places they are merely in the same direction as.  In this case molecular cloud Sagittarius B2 is described as being about 150 light years wide and 390 light years from the center of the galaxy.  Thus it is both an incredibly vast distance from the central point of the galaxy, but also very, very close to the center as seen from the many times vaster distance of Earth.

Comment: @M.A.Golding 390 light years is less than 1% the width of the galaxy.

Comment: Define "center". That would probably be pretty close to Sagittarius A*, and you won't "taste" anything there... And if not, you'd have to open your space suit to give the almost-nothing out there a lick. And... what is the question, anyhow? "Are there ethyl formate molecules out there?" Is that really so doubtful? "Does ethyl formate taste of strawberries?" Is *that* really so doubtful? "Would you actually *taste* strawberries out there?" -- *When you're doing what, exactly?*